# How to convert a specific integer to datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, strptime

For example, I have the int 043017, which I want converted to 04/30/17 (April 30, 2017), I want to be able to convert any int of that format into datetime, how can this be accomplished?

Comment: not *any int* will be valid in your case, for ex. `323216`

Comment: so is there a way to do it with my int, or  astring version of the int? so far nothing works

Answer (score 7):

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(input, '%m%d%y')
```

Comment: This is the way to do it, although it requires a string as input. An integer will not work. @Alex you should convert the integer to a string, and then use this method. Note that you cannot keep the leading 0 in a python integer. (You could check the string length and a pad as necessary)

Comment: it does not work with a string '043017', i tried %x also

Comment: @Alex It's working fine for me with this string. You cant print d to see it. Do you get any error?

Comment: ValueError: time data '043117' does not match format '%m%d%Y'  this is all it says. i dont know why

Comment: `%Y` is a four-digit year, so of course it doesn't match. `%y` is the format for a 2-digit year

Comment: @Alex You should use lowercase 'y'.

Comment: now that i got that, how can I convert '043017' to a string '04/30/17'

Comment: '/'.join([a[:2], a[2:4], a[4:]]) where a is your string